# In how many ways can the teachers at a conference be selected to take a quiz?

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

Q) There are $20$ teachers at a conference. Of these, $8$ are maths teachers, $6$ are history teachers, $4$ are physics teachers and $2$ are geography teachers.

a) Four of the teachers are to be chosen at random to take part in a quiz.

b) If they all must teach the same subject

C) In how many different ways can the teachers be chosen if there are to be at least two maths teachers?

For Part 1 what I did is $20C4$? Am I right?
Please provide logic of second and third part?

Comment: (a) yes; (b) you can choose 4 maths teachers in 8C4 ways, or 4 history teachers in 6C4 ways or 4 physics teachers in 1 way, so total 8C4+6C4+1. (c) There are 12C4 ways of choosing with 0 maths teachers, (8C1)(12C3) ways of choosing with 1 math teacher. Hence 20C4-12C4-(8C1)(12C3) ways with at least 2 math teachers.

Answer (score 3):

(a) yes;

(b) you can choose 4 maths teachers in 8C4 ways, or 4 history teachers in 6C4 ways or 4 physics teachers in 1 way, so total 8C4+6C4+1=86.

(c) There are 12C4 ways of choosing with 0 maths teachers, (8C1)(12C3) ways of choosing with 1 math teacher. Hence 20C4-12C4-(8C1)(12C3)=2590 ways with at least 2 math teachers.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the question is asking for the number of combinations, $20C4$ is correct being the number of combinations of choosing any $4$ from $20$ where order doesn't matter. For the number of combinations for part b), it's $8C4 + 6C4 + 1$ where there are simply either $4$ math teachers, $4$ history teachers or just one possibility of $4$ physics teachers. For c) $8C2\cdot 12C2 + 8C3\cdot 12C1 + 8C4 \cdot 12C0$ where it's the sum of the number of ways of choosing $2,3$ or $4$ math teachers times the number of ways of choosing $2, 1$ or $0$ other teachers respectively from the remaining $12$.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig. Yes you are correct, I'm over-counting. I'll revise my answer in the method you suggest. Thank you.